# Internal redirect on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains pointing at a WordPress site (`domain1.com` and `domain2.com`). I am using an Apache 2 web server and would like to have `domain1.com` act normally.

However, when a user accesses `domain2.com`, `domain1.com/test-category/test-page/` should be displayed, which has been generated by WordPress' rewrites. The hard bit is that I would like `domain2.com` to stay in the browser address bar (without `/test-category/test-page/`).

I thought it may be possible to do internal rewrites using .htaccess or with WordPress' `add_rewrite_rule` but have come to a bit of a block. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You might be able to set your DNS for domain2.com to domain1.com/test-category/test-page/ if that page will always be domain2's home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mod_proxy + [P] flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) of the RewriteRule, but it not ideal solution,because it is making extra http request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give me an example of code (I couldn't quite work this out)?